# System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type') OData Unit Test upgrade to .NET 6.0

Tags: .net, odata, .net-6.0

I have recently upgrading to .NET 6.0 and am now experiencing a previously unseen error before in my OData Unit Test project. I am experiecing a: System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type') error when running the following unit test:

```
        [Fact]
        public void Startup_Configure_Ok()
        {
            // Arrange   
            ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddOData();
            ServiceProvider provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            var appBuilder = new ApplicationBuilder(provider);       
            var routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(appBuilder);
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();

            Startup startup = new Startup(_fixture.GetConfiguration());

            // Act
            startup.Configure(appBuilder);

            // Assert
            Assert.True(true);
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Stack Trace:

```
  Message: 
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')

  Stack Trace: 
IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(Type type)
DefaultContainerBuilder.BuildContainer()
PerRouteContainerBase.CreateODataRootContainer(Action`1 configureAction)
PerRouteContainerBase.CreateODataRootContainer(String routeName, Action`1 configureAction)
ODataRouteBuilderExtensions.EnableDependencyInjection(IRouteBuilder builder, Action`1 configureAction)
ODataRouteBuilderExtensions.EnableDependencyInjection(IRouteBuilder builder)
StartupUnitTest.Startup_Configure_Ok() line 43
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with your DI framework. Are you sure it is compatible with .net 6?

Comment: I believe so, is there any way I can check if it is compatible

Comment: Hey @Ysefwakil, were you able to find root of this problem? I also have this error after upgrading some dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I saw the exactly same symptom and fixed by upgrading Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData version to 7.5.17.

Comment: I run into the same issue while upgrading to .NET 6, and this fixed it, it should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: I had a similar issue with `MapODataServiceRoute` in Net Framework and upgrading `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` to the latest (7.6.1) resolved the issue.

Comment: I was using Microsoft.AspnetCore.OData.7.5.2,  upgraded it to Microsoft.AspnetCore.OData.7.5.12 while upgrading my project to .net core 6.0..

https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/217

Comment: Similar problem with Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.2.0 during odata Action call with byte[] argument. Rolled back to 8.1.2.

Comment: Confirm. I was on version 7.5.7, and updating to 7.5.17 fixed the issue (.NET 7)

Comment: Seems to be fixed for Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.x (in 8.2.5)